# How to detect is my PC graphics card has/is DirectX 9 graphics processor with WDDM driver model 1.0

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, directx

[The info of the tag](https://superuser.com/tags/windows-10/info) `windows-10` says that the last minimum hardware requirement for Windows 10 is

> Graphics card: DirectX 9 graphics processor with WDDM driver model
> 1.0

Where can I see whether my PC meets this requirement or not?

If it's somewhere in `System Information`, then where exactly?

Comment: The tag information appears to be incorrect, since Windows 10, doesn't even use WDDM 1.0.  The minimum version is NOT WDDM 1.0. DX9, isn't even installed on Windows 10 by default.

Comment: @Ramhound does my laptop meet minimum requirements for Win 10 if it has DirectX 11 and WDDM 1.1 ?

Comment: The current version of WDDM built-into Windows 10 is WDDM 2.9.  The system requirements for Windows 10 are detailed on Microsoft's website.  Any questions with regards your hardware compatibility with Windows 10 can be answered by comparing your specifications of your hardware to that list. **I cannot determine if your hardware is compatible without information that goes beyond the scope of the question you have asked.**  I will be unable to answer any questions asked in a comment to this question or the answer you submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found by myself.

I need to open `DirextX Diagnostic Tool`.

DirectX version is specified on the first tab `System` and WDDM version is specified at the second tab `Display`.